# Dialogflow and Support Board integration: Error 400 while trying to get a refresh token, how can I resolve this issue?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I created an agent, followed this documentation https://board.support/docs/#dialogflow-sync but at the stage when I need to press "synchronize" to select scopes and get refresh token - I am getting error code 400: invalid_request.

I tried to log in into google account and got error 400 invalid_request.